# Control-M Workload Policy for Jobs waiting on Resource

Tags: automation, control-m

If a job (Job A) is already in the Monitoring Queue waiting on a Resource that is being used by another job (Job B) and a workload policy was created to stop any new instance of Job A from running. Will the workload policy only affect the new instance of Job A or will it also affect the Job that is already in the queue and waiting on Job B's resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workload policies affect all jobs that match the defined filter in the `Active Jobs File` regardless of when they were ordered.
See the below excerpt from the Control-M Workload Automation User Guide.
[image: Control-M Workload Automation User Guide: Workload Policies]